# rsync using --delete-excluded flag is still showing content in destination

Tags: rsync

I'm using rsync with --delete-excluded flag but I still see contents in the destination folder. I'm trying to exclude and delete excluded cache from all chromium like browsers. Here's what I'm doing

```
rsync -av --delete --exclude-from='exclude.txt' --delete-excluded /home/user /media/user/extDrive/backup/
```

```
the exclude.txt:￼
**/Default/Cache/**
```

I've also tried:

```
**/Default/Cache/
```

But I'm still seeing contents inside Default/Cache at the destination. It seems to be excluded correctly, but it's not deleting the contents from the destination.

Any ideas?

Comment: rsync can be finicky with the top level directory of the source and destination. Please edit your question with the exact source and destination syntax you are using. For example I had to change this `rsync --delete-excluded --archive --verbose --exclude-from=exclude_files /mnt/c/Users/dsmyt/* doug@s19.smythies.com:/media/sdb/backup/s18-windows` to this `rsync --dry-run --delete-excluded --archive --verbose --exclude-from=exclude_files /mnt/c/Users/dsmyt doug@s19.smythies.com:/media/sdb/backup/s18-windows` to get it to work properly.

Comment: ok, i edited to match. should i have used the --delete-excluded flag before my orgin position? wonder if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: Try changing the contents of `exclude.txt` from this `**/Default/Cache/**` to this `Default/Cache`.

Comment: wouldnt that just exclude 1 folder, namely /home/user/Default/Cache. from destination. the exclude while syncing seems to work correcly in globbing all folders with the path pattern containing 'Default/Cache' in all my folers as i have my browser profiles in a lot of different folders. i just dont know why its not dissappearing on the destination's end.